# Airport Extreme Add Wireless Clients Without Needing Password?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, airport-extreme

Under the Airport's Add Wireless Clients menu, there is a feature to allow me to grant access to my WPA protected network on the first attempt someone makes to connect, without requiring them to know the password.

Sounds great, but what settings does the client use?  If they enter my wireless network name and choose WPA under security, it will require a password.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves (it's been a while since I tried that option, and I'm not near my router to try), the client can enter an empty password, or, if it's UI requires a password, anything it thinks is valid should work (like all zeros).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find online the PIN is just supposed to appear on the client somehow. I've never seen this in practice and it doesn't occur with my mobile devices when I try to allow a client by PIN. I've never seen any further detail given about when or how the PIN appears. It may all just be a big hoax.